# Fragments inside a View Pager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Im using three fragments on a view pager , im using position id as reference and based on the position id my fragments are getting displayed , each fragment has different data in it , here is my code

```
 @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {

        if(position==1){
                Log.e("Fragment","Fragment 1::"+String.valueOf(i));
                if (!(i<3))
                {
                    new Progress(100).execute();
                    new Progress2(20).execute();
                    new Progress3(30).execute();
                }
                ++i;
                return SlideFragment.newInstance(1, " ");}

           if(position==2){
                Log.e("Fragment","Fragment 2");
                if (!(i<3))
                {
                    new Progress(40).execute();
                    new Progress2(50).execute();
                    new Progress3(90).execute();
                }
                ++i;
                return Slidetwo.newInstance(String.valueOf(2), " ");}
          if (position==3)
                Log.e("Fragment","Fragment 3");
                if (!(i<3))
                {
                    new Progress(50).execute();
                    new Progress2(10).execute();
                    new Progress3(40).execute();
                }
                ++i;
                return SlideThree.newInstance(String.valueOf(3), " ");


    }
```

In this code only the two log values are getting displayed , and even though the data of all the three fragments are getting displayed im not getting the log from all the three fragments and data in that fragment is being displayed when i swipe back to the other two fragments , I anybody know where i am wrong please help me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the `ViewPager` loads the current page and next 1 page in memory, by default.

Try [`setOffScreenPageLimit()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)).

example)

```
ViewPager viewPager;
viewPager.setOffScreenPageLimit(2);
```

Comment: I tried it , im if i apply mPager.setOffScreenpageLimit(2) . Im only getting the log value from fragment 1 and other two fragments are gone

Comment: mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3); when i use this im getting all the three logs , only for the first time when i run it from android studio again if i swipe the fragments im getting nothing @Suhyeon Lee

Comment: @TamilSelvan You better read the API document of `ViewPager.setOffScreenpageLimit()` first. It loads the page first time and retains them in memory, and getItem() method is called when the page is being loaded. If you want to get log whenever you change the page, you have to use `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use this.Start your position from 0;

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position)
{

    if(position==0){
            Log.e("Fragment","Fragment 1::"+String.valueOf(i));
            if (!(i<3))
            {
                new Progress(100).execute();
                new Progress2(20).execute();
                new Progress3(30).execute();
            }
            ++i;
            return SlideFragment.newInstance(1, " ");}

       if(position==1){
            Log.e("Fragment","Fragment 2");
            if (!(i<3))
            {
                new Progress(40).execute();
                new Progress2(50).execute();
                new Progress3(90).execute();
            }
            ++i;
            return Slidetwo.newInstance(String.valueOf(2), " ");}
      if (position==2)
            Log.e("Fragment","Fragment 3");
            if (!(i<3))
            {
                new Progress(50).execute();
                new Progress2(10).execute();
                new Progress3(40).execute();
            }
            ++i;
            return SlideThree.newInstance(String.valueOf(3), " ");


}
```